# Injecting data to controller with a spinner

Tags: angularjs

I have a SocketService (using socket.io) and I make a call to my backend server like so:

```
SocketService.on("get user data", (response) => {
    DataService.data = response;
});
```

I have a controller like so:

```
...
.controller("UserController", ($scope, DataService) => {
    SocketService.emit("get user data");
    $scope.users = DataService.data;
});
```

Now, this is the flow:

1. Controller loads, makes a request to our backend using SocketService.
2. $scope.users becomes equal to an empty array since we didn't get a response yet.
3. SocketService listens for the response, updates DataService.

The problem is, unless I click the button to load UserController again, I see an empty array. So, first click, I see an empty array. Second click after 1 seconds, I see the users array.

Is there any way to do something like this on Angular?

```
// pseudo code
SocketService.emit("get user data");
Spinner.show();

SocketService.on("get user data", (response) => {
    angular.controllers.resolve("UserController", ($scope) => {
        $scope.users = response;
    });
    Spinner.hide();
});
```

Comment: `SocketService.on('get user data', function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
    }); `This should work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your SocketService with socket.io, but if it were a normal angular service and call the backend via $http i would do following:

SocketService (inject $http):

```
function get(url, config) {
  return $http.get(url, config);
};
```

UserController (inject your SocketService):

```
function getUserData() {
  SocketService.get('myUrl', {})
    .then(function(response) {
       $scope.users = response.data;
    });
}
```

I hope this give you an impulse to solve your problem.

Comment: Sadly, socket.io doesn't provide promises. It only has syntax like so: `io.on("something"), (res) => {});` I thought about this but sadly socket.io limits me here.